# change the UI lang when using postgresql psql.exe

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 database, installed with Japanese as the main language. I am connecting from an English Windows 7 client using psql.exe. Is there any way to change the UI of the messages shown to me (e.g. the help, column headers from the \l command, etc) to English?

I know that I can set the character encoding using \encoding, but I really want to change the UI language from ja_JP to en_US (or similar).

I can't see anything in the psql documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: In a Linux environment, this is controlled by environment variables on the client.  If your OS is generally set to one language, psql should behave the same.  Not sure why that doesn't work in your case.

Comment: Delete or rename the `locale` folder. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811670/7818237

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows also, psql only looks at the LC_MESSAGES environment variable. Therefore this works...

```
set LC_MESSAGES=C
psql.exe
```

Comment: Powershell version:  
`$env:LC_MESSAGES = 'C'`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems. I tried to set locale properly during PostgreSQL installation, tried to change `postgresql.conf` but nothing helped to change the language in psql. Found out the UI language of `psql.exe` is controlled by environment variables in Windows. But `set LC_MESSAGES=C` modifies only current shell variable and it is saved temporarily, so as soon as you close the shell (or restart PC), your issue is back.

These 4 options change the UI language of `psql.exe` to English and make sure to keep this setting **persistently to avoid returning of the issue**:

- **Option 1**: Open Command Prompt and run: `setx LC_MESSAGES C`. Difference between `set` and `setx` is explained here: https://superuser.com/a/916652/1741056
- **Option 2**: Open Powershell run command: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LC_MESSAGES", "C", "User")`. See reference here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2#saving-environment-variables-with-setenvironmentvariable
- **Option 3**: In Windows GUI follow this steps: `System Properties` -> `Advanced` -> `Environment variables` -> `User variables` -> `New` -> Name: `LC_MESSAGES` -> Value: `C` -> `OK`
- **Option 4** (not a pure way! - but is works): Rename this folder `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8\share\locale\ja` (in case of Japan language and version 8 of PostgreSQL) to something different and restart shell. Here is the reference for this step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191428/change-language-of-system-and-error-messages-in-postgresql/56811670#comment121662022_56811670