# What is the difference between SETX and SET in environment variables in Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

> What is the difference between `SETX` and `SET`?

As per my understanding:
Both are used to set  environment variables
 `SETX` is for user variables.
 `SET` is for shell variables.

Comment: Try `SET /?` and `SETX /?` - that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Also, see SS64 references for [SET](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and [SETX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html). SS64 is a great command reference for several languages and command environments - I find it particularly handy for CMD & PowerShell.

Comment: Ans: http://superuser.com/a/832962/294054

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/647505/set-enviroment-variable-setx

Comment: http://coderjony.com/blogs/difference-between-set-and-setx-in-powershell/

Comment: `SET - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables for the duration of the current CMD session.` `SETX - Set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU) permanently.`

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not quite that simple. Environment variables are not limited by scope, as you suggest, but you are right that the lifetime of the value in the variable is different when comparing the verbs.

`set` modifies the current shell's (the window's) environment values, and the change is available immediately, but it is temporary.  The change will not affect other shells that are running, and as soon as you close the shell, the new value is lost until such time as you run set again.

`setx` modifies the value permanently, which affects all future shells, but does not modify the environment of the shells already running.  You have to exit the shell and reopen it before the change will be available, but the value will remain modified until you change it again.

See here for an example: http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2008/02/set-and-setx.html

Comment: that is very well written, I would add though, that setx changes the registry

Comment: It's actually even less simple than described here. There are "volatile" environment variables to be mindful of. And, under some circumstances, the list of variables shown by the SET command will differ depending on whether the user has invoked an "elevated" command prompt or not.

Answer (score 22):

Actually we can set variable at three scopes:
 1. Shell
 2. User
 3. System (Machine) or Global

### SET : Create or Update the current shell scope for temporary.

```
C:\Users\977246>set /?
Displays, sets, or removes cmd.exe environment variables.

SET [variable=[string]]

  variable  Specifies the environment-variable name.
  string    Specifies a series of characters to assign to the variable.

Type SET without parameters to display the current environment variables.
```

### SETX : Create or Update the current user environment variables for permanent.

```
C:\Users\977246>setx /?

SetX has three ways of working:

Syntax 1:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]

Syntax 2:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]

Syntax 3:
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]

Description:
    Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system
    environment. Can set variables based on arguments, regkeys or
    file input.

To remove the variable set value to empty string as follows

Example: setx path ""
```

**In GUI User and System environment variables.**

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Adding a point that was missed by other answerers.

To set a System Environment Variable rather than a User Environment Variable, we just need to use the /m option in the setx command and run it from an elevated(Administrator) Command Prompt.

```
setx variable value /m
```

Example:
Open Command prompt as administrator and run

```
setx Path "%Path%;C:\Users\User\Libs" /m
```

Explanation:
The above command will append "C:\Users\User\Libs" to the already existing Path Variable(System Environment Variable).

Without the **/m** argument, it will make changes to or create a User-level Path variable only.

From the setx user manual,

> /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
>                              the system wide (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
>                              environment. The default is to set the
>                              variable under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
>                              environment.

Comment: __ATTENTION: DO NOT USE THE POSTED COMMAND LINE TO REDEFINE THE SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE `PATH`!__ It is an absolute NO GO - NEVER EVER to redefine __system__ or __user__ environment variable `Path` with command __SETX__ using the string value of the __local__ environment variable referenced with `%Path%`. The result is a __system__ `Path` with all environment variable references expanded, with folder paths of __user__ `Path` appended resulting in duplicates in concatenated __local__ `Path` and perhaps removed folder paths caused by truncation of command __SETX__.

Comment: The redefinition of __system__ or __user__ `Path` from within a Windows command prompt window or using a batch file is really difficult, see for example [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) The batch code in this post is much better, but is nevertheless not 100% fail-safe.

Comment: Users should click on Windows __Start__ menu button, type on keyboard `environment` and Windows offers in language of Windows __Edit the system environment variables__ and __Edit environment variables for your account__. Then the user should click on one of the two items to open the dialog window in which the user can modify safely the __system__ and __user__ environment variables. For more details about `Path` management see also [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Answer (score 5):

`setx.exe` is a program that sets user/system environment variables in the *registry*, which is used for future process creation. `set` is a command that shows the *process* environment variables in the environment in the parameter block in the PEB of the current process (which show the user and system variables as well as variables defined by the current or parent processes using `set`), as well as allowing more variables to be defined in it by the current process, and the changes to the environment can be viewed from process explorer.

`cmd /c set variable=value` will set variables for the child process `cmd.exe` that it creates (which attaches itself to the parent `cmd.exe` console window and does not allocate its own, and inherits the parent's environment) so it won't take effect when you perform `set` after that from within the same window, because it be referring to the parent process `cmd.exe`. Top level processes inherit their environment directly from the registry and `explorer.exe` dynamically updates its environment variables (unlike most other apps), so when you `setx` it won't even update the current process environment, only the registry, which is either read by `explorer.exe`, or the `explorer.exe` process is updated by the windows API function that sets the environment variable (less likely), such that future opened `cmd.exe`s inherit `explorer.exe`'s environment, as they are children.