# Preserving environment variable references when using SETX

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

In Windows the path environment variable can refer to other environment variables:

[image: Environment variable referencing other environment variables]

However, if I update the path from the command line using SETX, those variables are dereferenced:

```
setx path %path%
```

[image: Variable refrerences have been replaced with actual paths]

Is there a way to set an environment variable from the command line that allows these references to other variables?

Comment: This will be a good place to start reading: https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for the link but my question is about referencing an environment variable inside another, from the command line, which your link doesn't touch on.