# Set Windows proxy with username , password permanently in cmd

Tags: windows, proxy, passwords, username

i know this method to set proxy and username

set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port

set FTP_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%

set HTTPS_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%

it works fine, but the problem is that once i restart the laptop it's gone forever and i have to retype it again.

Is there a smarter way to fix this permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows

Comment: @HelpingHand can you please give a working example (windows 10)