# Change user TEMP and TMP directory from command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to create a batch file to change the location of the TEMP and TMP files for the current user to another drive.  (And back again, but if I can do the one the reverse will be easy.)  However, while the command appears to take effect in the command prompt, it does not in the file explorer.

I don't want to do this manually from the environment variable window in settings, since I want a one-click batch file solution.  So I run the following from a command prompt, with Administrator permission:

```bash
c:\>set TMP=D:\temp

c:\>set TEMP=%TMP%
```

Then I check it as follows, and apparently it has worked:

```bash
c:\>d:

D:\>cd %tmp%

D:\temp>
```

However, when I open a file explorer window, and enter %TMP% in the file address, the folder goes to the usual location: C:\Users<localuser>\AppData\Local\Temp

This happens even if I start the folder window at the D: drive root.  The command prompt and file explorer appear to have a different setting for %TMP%.  I assume the file explorer is correct and the one windows will use, so my command prompt commands have not worked.

Am I missing something?

Comment: also https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows/916652#916652